# Specifying known_first_party and src_path still causes Isort to group my own module with third party imports

Tags: python, isort

The directory structure of my project is as follows:

```
.
└── Home/
    └── project/
        ├── data/
        │   ├── dataset.py
        │   └── data_utils.py
        ├── src/
        │   └── main.py
        ├── .pre-commit-config.yaml
        └── .isort.cfg
```

I also have a `.env` file that I'm using Python-dotenv to load that has the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set to `PYTHONPATH="$(pwd):$(pwd)/src:$(pwd)/data"` so that I can perform imports from within the `data` directory.

In the `data_utils.py` file I have an import that goes `from dataset import Dataset`. When I run my commits Isort groups `from dataset import Dataset` with the other third party import statements.

I've tried to specify the following in my `.isort.cfg` but none of them work:

1. `known_first_party=data_utils`
2. `known_first_party=data_utils` & `src_paths=data`

I'm a little stuck as to what else I could try.